# Using the mean value theorem to solve an inequality

Tags: calculus

If *f '* is increasing, show that

$\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h} \le f'(x) \le \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

for all *h>0*, specifically using the mean value theorem.

$f'(x) \le f'(c)$ is obviously true due to the fact that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(c)$ for some c, but I don't know how the left hand inequality relates at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, there exists some $c \in (x,x+h)$ such that
$$f'(c_+) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}.$$
Then $f'(x) \leq f'(c_+)$ since $f'$ is increasing.
Similarly, there exists some $c_- \in (x-h,x)$ such that
$$f'(c_-) = \frac{f(x) - f(x - h)}{h}.$$
Then $f'(x) \geq f'(c_-)$ since $f'$ is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have, $x < c < x+h$ and since $f^\prime$ is increasing, $f^\prime(x)\leq f^\prime(c)$. Do the same thing for the other side.